# What makes this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, scope

Why is this question off-topic?

[Using two parameters to delete using a Django DeleteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606762/using-two-parameters-to-delete-using-a-django-deleteview)

It clearly asks a question about a specific programming problem.  The question may have other issues, but it does not appear that "off-topic" is one of them.  So why was it closed as such?

Comment: I don't really get it either to be honest.

Comment: That off-topic banner message is spectacularly unhelpful.

Comment: I don't know, and it doesn't seem off topic to me. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Possibly because its unclear exactly what problem the OP was facing, but then I'm just guessing

Comment: @Sayse: The "unclear what you're asking" close reason is not new. It has been around for years. (Though that doesn't preclude people choosing the wrong reason anyhow...)